Text length in pixel seems to be different on different size monitor with same resolution
I want to make my website responsive and use some css to calculate text length and left position. I want to place something at the end of the text and to find the left position (or the end of text), I use the font width x number of letter to get the text length in px. Now, here is the question, why it looks different on my 2 monitors since its the same resolution? One is larger than the other, but same resolution, so normally if my text is 10px and have 10 letter, if should gives 100px wide and on the other screen, it should also be 100px even if the px are larger or smaller, but its really different. Any ideas on this? I must forget about something!
When I set the position to be the calculated px (and it place the item at the right place on first monitor) but when I try the other one it get further away.
Thanks!
My text start at 18px from left side so I add 18px at the end.
position: absolute;left: calc((8px * 20) + 18px)
Its a 24 wide screen vs laptop screen each 1920 x 1080
Just to make it as clear as possible, just imagine a text "HELLO WORLD" and I would like to add another text right after it so: "HELLO WORLD GOOD MORNING". If I calculate the HELLO WORLD width and place the "GOOD MORNING" at that left position, it should always be good. THe text size is always the same and the same number of letters. Question is why its different, it should just be bigger or smaller.
Another thing that looks weird is that if I add letter spacing, it looks different on tablet only. 0.21em looks larger on tablet in proportion (If again I put a text just after its ok on all monitor exept tablet). But one things at time! :)

PPI has a say in how different monitors display the same objects. An understanding of PPI may help you understand the issue. https://www.displayninja.com/what-is-pixel-density/

“I want to place something at the end of the text” ... please edit your post to include details of what this is. Please also include enough of your HTML and CSS to enable us to reproduce the issue for ourselves. Ideally you will include a stack snippet in your post which demonstrates the problem.

Indeed, this sounds like an XY problem. See - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Thanks for reply, but its not ppi issue. I will put another text right after the first one, so if I calculate the first text width, then I put the second one at the left position corresponding of the first text width... no matter ppi it should be fine. Like, if I add simply a letter at the end of first text, it wont get at a different place on the other monitor.

I found out a workaroud, I just use css to get the same text, font size etc but set it as invisible and in the same css, I set the new text with another font and visible this time. So its working but I still have no clue why the same pixel count get off that much on some screen! Maybe the way that the width is calculated (space are not as large as text) or something!
